# Cast request in gRPC interceptor to relevant protobuf message

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, grpc

I have a `UnaryServerInterceptor` that receives a `req` `Interface{}`. This `req` could be any one of my messages, but in this case all my messages have a `metadata` child message in common.

**Protobuf definitions (sample)**

```
message ClientMeta {
    string info = 1;
}

message PingRequest {
    ClientMeta metadata = 1;
}

message OtherRequest {
    ClientMeta metadata = 1;
}

service Blah {
    rpc Ping (PingRequest) returns (PingResponse) {}
    rpc Other (OtherRequest) returns (OtherResponses) {}
}
```

**Interceptor**

```
func (i *authInterceptor) unary() grpc.UnaryServerInterceptor {
    return func(
        ctx context.Context,
        req interface{},
        info *grpc.UnaryServerInfo,
        handler grpc.UnaryHandler,
    ) (interface{}, error) {
        log.Info().Msgf("interceptor: %s", info.FullMethod)
    }
}
```

I need to access the properties of the message's `metadata` in my interceptor. The problem is that I don't know which message it is, so I can't just cast it. I have several different messages but they all have `metadata` in common.

What's the best way to go about this?

Comment: Side note: Go doesn't have *casts*, but rather has type conversions, type switches, and type assertions. T(x) (where T is a type and x is a value) is a type conversion; x.(T) is a type assertion; and `switch x.(type) { ... }` is a type switch. There are some minor variations on this theme. The gRPC compiler sets things up so that you can use these (as in the already-accepted answer) reasonably cleanly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `protoc` generation should have produced a method called `GetMetadata` for both types. You can check if the incoming message implements an interface using a **type assertion** (see the [tour of go](https://tour.golang.org/methods/15) for more details), then call that method to get the metadata.

```
type HasMetadata interface {
    GetMetadata() *ClientMeta
}
```

In the function that handles the message, do something like this

```
if m, ok := req.(HasMetadata); ok {
    return m.GetMetadata()
}
```